# Highlight all selected items on a expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview, highlight, items

i'm trying to highlight one or more items in a expandablelistview. i found many solutions, but nothing could help me. 
I hope, somebody can help me. I have a database with cocktails. In the app you can create a new cocktail. The ingredients of a cocktail should be selected by the user in a expandablelistview. I only can highlight one item at the same time. But for better user experience it is important, that the user can select more than one item. If he has all ingredients selected, he can save his selection and the activity will close. If he forgot an ingredient, so he can start the activity again and he will see all the items highlighted, he had just selected and select the forgotten items.

I hope, my english is not so bad and you can understand what i mean and help me.

Here is the activity what will start to select ingredients for a cocktail:

```
public class SelectIngredientByCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
private ExpandableListView ingredients;
private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<String> listDataHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private DBConnection db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_ingredient_by_category);

    db = new DBConnection(getApplication());

   /* ... */

    ingredients = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elvIngredientsByCategory);
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplication(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    ingredients.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    ingredients.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            String ingredientName = (String) listAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            /* ... */

           /* 
           * if item is selected
           * mark item blue
           * if not
           * mark item red
           */

            return false;
        }
    });
}

public void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>(); //category
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); //ingredient

    listDataHeader = db.getAllCategoryIngredientsName();

    List<String> tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < listDataHeader.size(); i++) { 
        tmp = db.getAllIngredientByCategory(listDataHeader.get(i));
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), tmp);
    }
}

/* ... */
```

}

This is my adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> category;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> ingredient;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> category,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> ingredient) {
    this._context = context;
    this.category = category;
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this.ingredient.get(this.category.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_item, null);
    }

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    TextView child = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListChild);
    child.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this.ingredient.get(this.category.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this.category.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.category.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exp_list_group, null);
    }

    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    final TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

And here the xml-files:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Ingredient.SelectIngredientByCategory"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/elvIngredientsByCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListChild"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: I found a solution for my problem. Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can set background color to the selected child view

```
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4482e5"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what is, if the user select the wrong ingredient? I have tried this way, but i couldn't change the color again to the standard color. I tried this with setSelected, but it does not work. I only could highlight one or more items. But deselect does not work... Any idea, how i can do this?